# Partition restoration

Tags: partitioning

Good afternoon. 
Downloaded Partition Scanner & Disk Recovery Tool via Terminal. Synaptic Package Manager helped to install it. When it runs says: **Cannot execute command ' '/usr/bin/partitionmanager-bin --dontsu''.**
Seems that I do not have "administrative privileges."
Time is passing and I need some help. One of my drives has lost a partition. Just not there to be seen at all. It's a NTFS format which is rarely written to used as source of video files for playing. Would appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed with this. 
Rgds & thanks

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using Gparted its very easy to use and one of the best partition manager out there , yeah even comparing windows paid apps here is the [LINK](http://gparted.org/download.php) to live cd or install locally using `sudo ap-get install gparted`  and for partition recovery there is a awesome free tool called testdisk and photorec utility for data recovery,it gets installed with testdisk metapackage

to install testdisk

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

[LINK](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) for testdisk usage

[LINK](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) for photorec usage

Comment: Thanks. Downloaded that with Terminal. Last line reads:-

Comment: ok autoremove is for removing orphaned packages and in your case it isn't needed here if you want to modify resize partitions use gparted and if you want to recover partition data use testdisk follow the tutorial link i have given and if this answer was helpful to you then help people like us help you give a vote.Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks tyson blader. Very grateful. Back on to this shortly - distractions galore here! I'll let you know in due course,

Comment: Hello again!  I am struggling here. Gparted downlaoded & installed and yes I can run it. Not quite what I need though as it sees only one of the 2 Partitions and offers only to make more with dire warnings about data back-up.  TESTDISK: Downloaded and installed after messing with Synaptic Package Manager (again) but the software doesn't show up in the dash and I therefore cannot run it. Sorry if I sound such a duffer.  I am trying though but my head is clouding over again. That data is backed up but me oh my - such a lot! Best part of 2Tb on that drive in 2 equal 1Tb Partitions.

Comment: testdisk is a command-line utility for rescuing partitions so as photorec thats why it does not show up in dash the two link i have provided shows step by step usage of those two utilities,sorry but in Linux sooner or later you have to use command-line heavy stuff to troubleshoot problems.

Comment: if you have all data backed up and don't need the lost partition data then just format the whole hard drive and recreate the partition table from scratch.

Comment: Dude i never offend anybody sorry if i offended you,im not a guru im a student too,and i never came across any gui utility in linux that recovers partitions.Maybe there is a utility with gui for partition recovery,but i never came across one that actually did what i needed.

Comment: No worries! Between you - is there more than one of you..... I have got this done. Not easy for a hair lip like me but would be for a normal person! First of all is due a really hearty thankyou and right to call me anything you want! Somewhere was asked if any suggestions. Yeah one or two:- To start Testdisk in Terminal type "testdisk" and Enter. The correct Partition structure is given by GParted (and other refs) in my case NOT the default but next one down (was it GUI?). Anyway follow on screen to see files in original partition and confirm this is to be kept/re-written Apart from that :>))